# Firefox 60 crashes on launch after Lubuntu 17.10.1 or 18.04 LTS installed

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, 17.10, 18.04, crash

I did a new install of Lubuntu 17.10.1 on a 700 MHz Athlon Thunderbird PC with 768MB RAM. Firefox crashed when opened, so I ran software update and upgraded Firefox to 60.0.1 which did not solve the problem.

Upgrading to Lubuntu 18.0.4 did not fix it. Same problem: ThreadIDNameMapping: 934: "Gecko_IOThread"

I also added Chromium, and at launch, got "The application "Chromium Web Browser" has quit unexpectedly".

Out of the box, it doesn't work, and it doesn't give enough information to understand the problem. So far, I am unimpressed. Is there some other known issue that causes Firefox to crash that I can fix?

The installer says 19 packages are no longer supported by Canonical. Sounds ominous; is it?

Comment: Packages not supported does not refer to major apps like Firefox. It's no big thing.